# Is measuring js execution time a way to tell how quickly the app is responding to requests?

Tags: performance, node.js, heroku, express

I have something like a microtime() function at the very start of my node.js / express app.

```
function microtime (get_as_float) {
    // Returns either a string or a float containing the current time in seconds and microseconds  
    // 
    // version: 1109.2015
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/microtime
    // +   original by: Paulo Freitas
    // *     example 1: timeStamp = microtime(true);
    // *     results 1: timeStamp > 1000000000 && timeStamp < 2000000000
    var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    var s = parseInt(now, 10);

    return (get_as_float) ? now : (Math.round((now - s) * 1000) / 1000) + ' ' + s;
}
```

The code of the actual app looks something like this:

```
application.post('/', function(request, response) {
  t1 = microtime(true);
  //code
   //code
   response.send(something);
   console.log("Time elapsed: " + (microtime(true) - t1));
}
```

> Time elapsed: 0.00599980354309082

My question is, does this mean that from the time a POST request hits the server to the time a response is sent out is give or take ~0.005s?

I've measured it client-side but my internet is pretty slow so I think there's some lag that has nothing to do with the application itself. What's a quick and easy way to check how quickly the requests are being processed?

Comment: That just tells you low long it took to process the function. To do the entire process you would have to hook express at the first input and log on the final exit of the express process loop. You might be able to use express.logger for that, or you might want to write your own middleware provider for this.

Comment: Is it possible to do those things when hosting on heroku?

Comment: I don't know what you're allowed to configure on heroku, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shameless plug here. I've written an agent that tracks the time usage for every Express request.

http://blog.notifymode.com/blog/2012/07/17/profiling-express-web-framwork-with-notifymode/

In fact when I first started writing the agent, I took the same approach. But I soon realized that it is not accurate. My implementation tracks the time difference between request and the response by substituting the Express router. That allowed me to add tracker functions. Feel free to give it a try.